# Rapidminer/Netbeans Integration Error

Tags: java, netbeans, integration, rapidminer

I am trying to load a ready rapidminer model through netbeans...The whole application seems to be running fine except when i get an error at this line of code:

```
IOContainer ioResult = process.run();
**ExampleSet resultSet = (ExampleSet) ioResult.getElementAt(0);**
ExampleTable mytable = resultSet.getExampleTable();
```

The error is this one...

```
com.rapidminer.Process run
INFO: Process C:\Users\Antonis\.RapidMiner5\repositories\Local Repository\yo.rmp      finished successfully after 0 s
**Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:        com.rapidminer.operator.learner.bayes.SimpleDistributionModel cannot be cast to   com.rapidminer.example.ExampleSet**
```

I don't know how to handle this...If you could please help me find a way to make it work...I am trying to fix it and i feel that i am sooo close...!!! thank you in advance for your ideas and time!!!

Comment: I hope my answer in the forum will help.

Comment: which answer are you talking about?

Comment: http://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php/topic,7456.msg25805.html#msg25805

Comment: ow yes but the problem is that i am not that experienced with java and i couldn't make something out of your answer... ;/ I think i am doomed...or i need some more detailed explanation...i run my rapidminer model and i get results with predictions in the "example set" results window...I just want to  print out the prediction(label) column of that rapidminer results in my netbeans application and i am finished...I know how to do it using the example set java commands but that does not apply to my model...can you pls help me find another way to print that column in my netbeans applcation...???